# Roblox animation not playing when I click

Tags: animation, lua, scripting, roblox

My Roblox animation isn't playing when I click. Here is the script I've used to make it do so:

```lua
local Tool = script.Parent
local Animation = Tool.Animation
 
Tool.Activated:Connect(function()
    local Character = Tool.Parent
    local Humanoid = Character.Humanoid
    
    local AnimationTrack = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(Animation)
    AnimationTrack:Play()
end)
```

The tool's name is Weight, but it doesn't matter if I change it or not. It still does not trigger my animation. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Animation have levels as:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EBlT.png)

and press : Set Animation Priority
and select a level

this sets the priority of animation. If the problem is not related to this, we need complete information or you can find detailed information at https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Animation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this script and it works. It doesn't stop playing, but I'm not sure if that's a priority of yours. However, I'd like to ask if your animation priority is set to action, as I think that would affect it.

Edit: If my suggestion does work, I'd also recommend adding this to make the animation stop after one play:

```
wait(1)  
AnimationTrack:Stop()
```

It may not be the best solution but it worked for me, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure you animation plays, and as Furkan Bilgin said, change the priority. To make sure it only plays once, make sure you don't check the "Loop" box in the animation editor.

If it is Loop is active, it will play forever.

You can also change this in the code by doing

```lua
AnimationTrack.Looped = false
```